# How to add color to a div using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i'm working a project using vuejs, the project is color pallete generator, i managed to add random color, however i couldnt add color to the div when i press the button, would u like to give me an example on how to fix it
thank you

```
 <template>
         <section class="bg">
         <h1>Color Palette generator</h1>
         <div class="colors">
         <div class="item" >
         <div class="color">
         
         </div>
         <p>{{colors}}</p>
         </div>
        
        
        
         </div>
         <div class="btnDiv">
            <button class="button " v-on:click="add">Generate Palette</button>
         </div>
         </section>
        </template>
        
        <script>
        import ColorPicker from './ColorPicker.vue'
        export default {
          components: {
            ColorPicker,
          },
          name: 'ColorPicker',
          props: {
            msg: String
          },
          data: function () {
            return {
         colors:''
            
            }
          },
          methods:{
            add : function() {
          var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
          var color = '#';
          for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            this.colors = color
            
          }
          console.log(this.colors)
        
         
        }
          }
        }
        </script>
        
        <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
        <style scoped>
     
        </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can bind variable to inline style in your template.

`<p :style="{'background-color' : colors}">{{colors}}</p>`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      colors: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
      var color = "#";
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        this.colors = color;
      }
      console.log(this.colors);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section class="bg">
    <h1>Color Palette generator</h1>
    <div class="colors">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="color"></div>
        <p :style="{'background-color' : colors}">{{colors}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btnDiv">
      <button class="button" v-on:click="add">Generate Palette</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```